# Can't compile Tokumx on FreeBSD

Tags: mongodb, freebsd, tokumx

I'm trying to build Tokumx on FreeBSD 10, but I'm stuck with the following error:

```
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/third_party/ft-index/portability/CMakeFiles/tokuportability_static_conv.dir/toku_crash.cc.o
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp: In function 'int mongo::pal::{anonymous}::addrtosymstr(void*, char*, int)':
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:71:9: error: 'Dl_info_t' was not declared in this scope
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:71:19: error: expected ';' before 'symbolInfo'
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:72:30: error: 'symbolInfo' was not declared in this scope
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:75:13: error: 'symbolInfo' was not declared in this scope
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:87:25: error: 'symbolInfo' was not declared in this scope
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp: In function 'int mongo::pal::backtrace_emulation(void**, int)':
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:106:57: error: 'walkcontext' was not declared in this scope
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp: In function 'int mongo::pal::{anonymous}::addrtosymstr(void*, char*, int)':
/home/tokumx/mongo/src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp:92:5: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/mongo/util/CMakeFiles/stacktrace.dir/stacktrace.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/third_party/ft-index/portability/CMakeFiles/tokuportability_static_conv.dir/toku_path.cc.o
gmake[2]: *** [src/mongo/platform/CMakeFiles/platform.dir/backtrace.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [src/mongo/platform/CMakeFiles/platform.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/mongo/util/CMakeFiles/stringutils.dir/base64.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object src/third_party/ft-index/portability/CMakeFiles/tokuportability_static_conv.dir/toku_pthread.cc.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object src/third_party/ft-index/portability/CMakeFiles/tokuportability_static_conv.dir/toku_time.cc.o
Linking CXX static library libtokuportability_static_conv.a
[ 28%] Built target tokuportability_static_conv
Linking CXX static library libstacktrace.a
[ 28%] Built target stacktrace
Linking CXX static library libstringutils.a
[ 28%] Built target stringutils
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

My cmake call looks like this:

```
CC=gcc47 CPP=cpp47 CXX=g++47 cmake --disable-warnings-as-errors -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D TOKU_DEBUG_PARANOID=OFF -D USE_VALGRIND=OFF -D USE_BDB=OFF -D BUILD_TESTING=OFF -D TOKUMX_DISTNAME=1.5.0 ..
```

The option "--disable-warnings-as-errors" was mentioned in a mongodb issue, but I'm not sure whether the cmake call is the right place to put this option.

**EDIT:**

Compiling Mongodb 2.6.4 works, but surprisingly only the raw source and not the port with patches applied:

```
Install file: "build/freebsd/normal/mongo/mongod" as "mongod"
scons: done building targets.
[root@testbox /usr/ports/databases/mongodb/work/mongodb-src-r2.6.4]#
```

**EDIT#2:**

Meanwhile I made some progress and patched `CMakeLists.txt`and added the following compiler flags:
-lexecinfo -lpthread

-lexecinfo fixes the missing backtrace_symbols_fd issue in src/mongo/platform/backtrace.cpp
-lpthread fixes the pthread error in thrd_party/ft-fix

Now I'm stuck with the next error:

```
[ 52%] Building CXX object src/mongo/client/CMakeFiles/mongocommon_client.dir/model.cpp.o
/mnt/qno/mongo/src/mongo/client/model.cpp: In member function 'virtual bool mongo::Model::load(mongo::BSONObj&)':
/mnt/qno/mongo/src/mongo/client/model.cpp:27:17: error: 'getScopedDbConnection' is not a member of 'mongo::ScopedDbConnection'
/mnt/qno/mongo/src/mongo/client/model.cpp: In member function 'virtual void mongo::Model::remove(bool)':
/mnt/qno/mongo/src/mongo/client/model.cpp:44:17: error: 'getScopedDbConnection' is not a member of 'mongo::ScopedDbConnection'
/mnt/qno/mongo/src/mongo/client/model.cpp: In member function 'virtual void mongo::Model::save(bool)':
/mnt/qno/mongo/src/mongo/client/model.cpp:59:17: error: 'getScopedDbConnection' is not a member of 'mongo::ScopedDbConnection'
```

I can't find anything related on google.

Comment: TokuMX isn't officially supported on FreeBSD and might not work.  But this particular error is in code that's unchanged from MongoDB.  Are you able to compile MongoDB 2.4 from source?

Comment: I haven't tried compiling Mongo yet, but I've applied the patches from the freebsd ports for mongo. They change a few things in Scons as well as 4 or 5 source files. None of them seem to target the issue I'm having - I suspect it's a missing compile flag or similar, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest making sure you can compile basic mongodb first, with and without the patches from ports, then looking at the diff of that file, and also running make with `VERBOSE=1` for tokumx, and running scons without --mute, so you can compare the compilation flags.

Comment: Compiling mongodb works fine. I just build 2.6.4 successfully